# Elastic Search Batch file not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I installed elastic search on my local node and was running the ELK stack on same node a day before. I closed it and then the next day again tried starting it but now the elasticsearch bat file wont start. I click on the file and command prompt starts and closes in an instance and it wont start again.

Comment: Open cmd window.  Cd to Elasticsearch bin folder.  Run bat file through this window.  What is the output?

Comment: You could also look at the logs sub-directory

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of what your problem was -

1. First go to edit environment variables
2. Go to system variables section
3. Add a new path or edit the old java home path to >> JAVA_HOME or ES_JAVA_HOME : the current java path till jdk-{version}
4. Add it
5. Then go to path and double click
6. Edit the path till bin this time
   Do these you elasticsearch.bat file not opening will be solved.